# Ember: Get route instance from the controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a multi-step flow that the user can go through sequentially or jump straight to a section (if the sections in between are completed). I think this logic should be in the Route object. However, from within the controller, how do I access the route instance. For example, it would be ideal to be able to do something like this in the controller:

```
App.Flow = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  submit: function(){
    // Validation and XHR requests
    // ...

    // Go to the next step
    route.goToNextStep();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From within a controller, you can access the router via `this.get('target')`. So `this.get('target').send('goToNextStep')` should work.

Like so:

```
App.Flow = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  submit: function(){
    // ...
    this.get('target').send('gotoNextStep');
  }
}

App.FlowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    gotoNextStep: function(){
      // ...
      this.transitionTo(routeName);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the route for such conditions,
so from the controller just say,

```
App.Flow = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  submit: function(){
    var self =this;
    // Validation and XHR requests
    // ...

    // Go to the next step
    self.send('goToNextStep');
  }
}
```

and define your `goToNextStep` event in your route's event hash

Answer (score 0):

'this' is what points to the router, but you shouldn't add any methods to that prototype. Instead, make some sort of event that triggers the transition to the next step.

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't very clear. `this` in the example would point to the controller object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `target`, another way to do this in Ember now is with [`getOwner`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/functions/@ember%2Fapplication/getOwner).

For example, to send an action to your application route:

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object'; // https://github.com/pzuraq/ember-decorators-polyfill
import { getOwner } from '@ember/application';

export default class MyTopLevelComponent extends Component {
    @action
    closeModal() {
      getOwner(this).lookup('route:application').send('closeModal');
    }
});
```